# Different submenus if SQL result is empty

Tags: php, html

I have a menu with different submenus, where I want to show a different specific sub-submenu if the SQL result is empty or not.

If the username (the session username) exist in that database, it will output the firstname and lastname, since `$result` is not empty. However, if I login to an account that does not have the username in that database, I does not output the `<li class='last'><a href=""><span>SubSub1: EMPTY RESULT</span></a></li>`.

It just outputs this:

```
                <li class='active has-sub'><a href=""><span>Sub1</span></a>
                    <ul>
                                            </li>
                    </ul>
```

When it should have been:

```
            <li class='active has-sub'><a href=""><span>Sub1</span></a>
                <ul>
                    <li class='last'><a href=""><span>SubSub1: EMPTY RESULT</span></a></li>
                </ul>
```

Why does it come out empty? What am I doing wrong?

```
<form action="user.php" method="GET">
<div id="cssmenu">
    <ul>
        <li class='active has-sub'><a href='#'><span><?php echo htmlentities($_SESSION['username'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?></span></a>
            <ul>
                <tr>
                    <li class='last'><a href=""><span>Menu1</span></a></li>
                    <li class='last'><a href=""><span>Menu2</span></a></li>
                    <li class='active has-sub'><a href=""><span>Menu3</span></a>
                        <ul>
                        <li class='active has-sub'><a href=""><span>Sub1</span></a>
                            <ul>
                            <?php
                            require('connections/db_connection.php');
                            $username = $_SESSION['username'];


                            $sql = "SELECT name, lastname FROM servers";
                            $sql .= " WHERE username = '$username'";

                            $result = $connection->query($sql);

                            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
                                $name = $row['name'];
                                $lastname = $row['lastname'];
                                if (empty($result)){
                                ?>
                                        <li class='last'><a href=""><span>SubSub1: EMPTY RESULT</span></a></li>
                                <?php
                                }else{
                                ?>
                                        <li class='last'><a href=""><span>SubSub1: <?php echo $name; ?><br>
                                        Last name: <?php echo $lastname; ?></span></a></li>
                                        <li class='last'><a href=""><span>SubSub2</span></a></li>
                                    <?php
                                }

                            }

                            $connection->close();
                            ?>
                        </li>
                            </ul>
                        <li class='last'><a href=""><span>Sub2</span></a></li>
                        <li class='last'><a href=""><span>Sub3</span></a></li>
                    </li>
                    </ul>
                    <li class='last'><a href="logout.php"><span>Logout</span></a></li>
                </tr>   
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: Are you speaking about selected rows = 0 or empty field in database with name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `$result` is empty - you will never enter

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
```

as there's nothing to fetch.

So I suppose you should check number of returned rows. Number will be `1` if a user is found in your database and `0` - otherwise.
So code can be like this (I suppose you use `mylsqi`):

```
$result = $connection->query($sql);
if (0 < $result->num_rows) {
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc(); // you can fetch only one result if you're sure that there's only one user;
    $name = $row['name'];
    $lastname = $row['lastname'];?>
    <li class='last'><a href="">
        <span>SubSub1: <?php echo $name; ?><br>
        Last name: <?php echo $lastname; ?>
        </span>
    </a></li>
    <li class='last'><a href=""><span>SubSub2</span></a></li>
<?php
} else {
     // no user found:?>
     <li class='last'><a href=""><span>SubSub1: EMPTY RESULT</span></a></li>
<?php
}
```

And be the way:

```
    </li>
</ul>
```

Remove this `</li>` as you already closing `li` in your `if`s.

Comment: Thanks! I don't think I would have realized that. Will try it out when I'm back at the computer.